# Disable SUPER / WINKEY key in remmina

Tags: remmina

I use remmina all the time and this is driving me mad. I can't figure out how to disable the <kbd>WINKEY</kbd> key.

When I connect to a remote computer (a Windows computer) from Ubuntu 13.10 & Remmina, when I press <kbd>E</kbd> Windows Explorer opens. When I press <kbd>L</kbd> the computer locks, <kbd>D</kbd> shows the desktop, and so forth. It's as if the <kbd>WINKEY</kbd> key is stuck on my keyboard.

I am going crazy having to use the character map. Worse yet, now with the ever-so-awesome Windows 8 start menu, or lack of, I cannot even browse to the character map.

I have to type Character Map. but if anyone uses Windows, you'll know what happens when you hold the <kbd>WINKEY</kbd> and start typing <kbd>c-h-a-r-a-c-t-e-r m-a-p</kbd>.

How to solve this ?

Comment: A quick double-tap of the WINKEY works for me! Thanks @Rmano!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Comment moved to the answer because it seems to work.*

Remmina 0.99.9 works ok for me, but I use it to connect to Linux via VNC only.

There is a bug that can be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/993432 --- is this your problem?

In that bug, one user says that **clicking two times WINKEY rapidly** solves the problem (open and close windows menu).

Comment: It works for me, ubuntu 15.05 however; I want to shift windows around super-left, super-right, to shift windows. This is particularly useful as the machine I connect to has two monitors and this lets me shift out of window screen back on screen (the system remembers where the windows was last used and restores it to that spot, which is typically off screen).